# Is GLib's GHashTable thread-safe for read-only accesses from multiple threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, glib

I want to create a GHashTable in program's initialization, which would be later concurrently accessed for reading only by newly created threads.

Is it safe to do so without a lock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, mutual exclusion is only needed when you could be modifying data concurrently with reading or modifying in another thread. If all accesses (after the hash table is filled in during initialization) are just reading, there's no need for locks.

Comment: Thanks, Barmar. I do know that, for the general case, this is true. My doubt is if this can be expected for GLib's data structures too, as the documentation leaves this open [here](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html): "GLib itself is internally completely thread-safe (all global data is automatically locked), but individual data structure instances are not automatically locked for performance reasons. For example, you must coordinate accesses to the same GHashTable from multiple threads."

Comment: Why would they be any different? Do you think that reading a structure might need to modify it behind the scenes?

Comment: I edited my comment before seeing your answer, sorry. As I said, documentation leaves a doubt, and I don't have experience with GLib. I must admit, though, that it would make no sense if GLib would require such locks.

Comment: GHashTable is absolutely not threadsafe, reading the source is the easiest way to verify that.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, C makes no guarantees, unless you have *some* sort of synchronisation, that data written by one thread is going to be visible or coherent to others.

You need a memory operation with "release" semantics after setting up the hash table, and one with "acquire" semantics in the other threads before they read it.

It's probably enough that the reading threads are created after the hash table is created, though I'm not 100% certain of this.

Comment: I think that this wouldn't be a problem in my case, as you said, but it is an interesting point to keep in mind. Could you point me one or more links where this is further explained? Thanks!

Comment: @DouglasSantos There's some videos here: http://concurrencyfreaks.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/the-new-memory-model-in-c11-and-c11.html FWIW C11 and C++11 have very similar requirements in regards to memory consistency models. cppreference has a good breakdown of the different types of ordering requirement, which are also applicable to C: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order - and of course the most authoritative source is the language specification itself, though it's not light reading.